# Why do undergraduate admissions in the U.S take into account nonacademic criteria?

Tags: undergraduate

College admissions in the U.S. takes into account many factors that are rarely considered in other countries and seem unrelated to academics.  For example, legacy status (children of alumni may be given preference), athletics, extracurricular activities, etc.  Why do these nonacademic criteria play a larger role in the U.S. than they do elsewhere?

Comment: This is related to (and possibly--but not really--a duplicate of): http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44107/how-does-hiking-in-himalayas-show-academic-promise

Comment: A cynical but not implausible view is that by taking extracurriculars into account, schools are able to favor the children of the relatively elite classes in the US -- whose enrollment in turn makes a college more desirable to other elites. See e.g. Mitchell Stevens's book [Creating a Class](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674034945) , an ethnography of how US private college admissions process serves "privileged families and the impressive organizational machinery they have developed to pass their comfortable social positions on to their children” (p.3)

Comment: Related question : http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16367/948

Comment: Do they really do this?

Comment: @gerrit Definitely. There are high correlations with extracurricular activities and graduation rates and GPA. Besides, how else do you compare a bunch of 3.8 GPAs all from different high schools and backgrounds?

Comment: @AustinHenley I'm used to the system where they admit any student meeting the criteria and likely to succeed, and that competition only comes in when competing for merit-based scholarships.  An Erasmus Mundus Master Course I was at would admit 150–200 out of 500 applicants, but award 35–40 scholarships, with 45–50 students actually starting.  Why reject likely successful students paying high tuition fees, when 50 extra students in a course can easily pay toward hiring an additional undergraduate lecturer and/or rooms for teaching on a satellite campus?

Comment: @gerrit At most good US colleges (say, top-30 or so), that would likely result in getting 5-10x of their current enrollment numbers (at least). Many (most?) undergrads are not on scholarships either way and are paying through loans and/or parents.

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer, but @AustinHenley touches on another aspect. With grade inflation in the US in high school, colleges (even non-prestigious ones) need additional information in order to determine who to admit. If you have 1,000 applicants who all have a 4.0 GPA and a 1550 on the SAT, but only 100 available spots, you need a way to determine who to select. This can be done by looking at other factors, whether they correlate to college performance or not.

Comment: Dutch medical courses simply draw lots in that situation. (Anyone average grades above 8/10 is admitted directly, but that is rare.  I've never met a 10/10 student, but I did read about one of those once, he made the national news.  I don't quite understand why grade inflation is so severe in the USA, and it also makes it difficult for students from countries with less grade inflation to get in, but that is a different question.)

Comment: @gerrit I don't think grade inflation in the US really affect international students. Most US universities already have quotas on how much of each incoming class can be from outside the US, and I think those are the bottleneck there. And I think that I would prefer being evaluated on extracurriculars over a random drawing.

Comment: Why not invite them all to write a test designed by the university?  Surely the university should be able to design a test where the majority of those applicants will fail and only a small minority will score over 90%.

Comment: @gerrit There's a million obvious reasons why that isn't feasible or desireable. Many have been stated in the comments and answers to these questions. Too add to them, what would you even test? One of the greatest things about the US education system is that kids don't have to choose a future career path until very late in their education.

Comment: @gerrit You think a test can predict success? Also, you're going to remove any diversity by only admitting the type of students that your test is designed for.

Comment: @AustinHenley I don't see how designing a test and admitting students based on test scores is any different from considering grade point averages at all.  Personally, I see tests as a necessary evil.  They are not the best predictor for success at all, but possibly better than a person's baseball skills or hiking experience.  I do understand from Anonymous' answer that, for example, *Harvard's primary goal isn't to educate smart people, but rather to have an impact on the world by educating influential people*, which does clear up a misunderstanding for me, but not every school is Harvard...

Comment: @gerrit Designing and administering a standardized test is more expensive than using GPAs that are already built into the educational system. Additionally, these tests already exist in the US and we know they have low correlation with college success rates. Creating more of these tests wouldn't help the situation; it would create additional and repetitive tasks college applicants need to complete in order to apply to a variety of schools. If I need to take test A for admission to school A, and test B for school B, I've now had to complete two tests that (hypothetically) measure the same thing.

Comment: **Please take extended discussion to [chat].**

Comment: As a high school student, I can attest that people obsessed with college are more concerned with "volunteering" for NHS (of course, without actually doing any volunteer work and preferably securing some free food for themselves) than studying anything even vaguely related to the careers that are the cause of their obsession with college. In effect, not only are the nonacademic criteria useless, they actually hurt students by encouraging them to waste time on nonsense instead of studying or enjoying their lives.

Comment: Why is this question on-topic here?  Our [help] says: ["please do not ask questions about undergraduate-specific issues"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Isn't this question off-topic, according to that rule?

Comment: I don't see this as being undergraduate-specific in that sense.  As I understand it (others may disagree), policy or historical questions related to undergraduate studies are OK, as long as they are of genuine interest to faculty or grad students.  Mainly, the restriction is meant to rule out a flood of questions on how to get into college or how college works, but I see this question as something academics at all levels might wonder about (especially those outside the U.S.).

Comment: @gerrit there is a huge difference between GPA and standardized tests for people who have learning disabilities like dyslexia, ADHD, and dyspraxia. Many talented students with learning disabilities do poorly on standardized tests, but excel in their classes especially those based on projects and not only exams. GPA allows that to be taken into consideration as well. Also, looking at extra curriculars allows students to show case what they can achieve outside the testing environment e.g. for a computer science major contributions to open source projects would be relevant

Answer (score 73):

As with any complicated social phenomenon, there is no simple and conclusive answer.  However, here are two important factors:

1. The U.S. didn't have world-class universities until the 20th century.  Even ones that are world-famous today (such as Harvard or Yale) did not particularly impress 19th century Europeans.  These universities had started out as vocational schools for pastors and gradually turned into finishing schools for the elite, but they weren't scholarly powerhouses.  In the early 20th century, there started to be more academic competition for admission.  This was very upsetting to the traditional students (largely wealthy young men from prep schools), who didn't want to be around too many Jews or other minorities or to have to compete with nerds for grades.  One tactic universities used in response was quotas for Jews, but the Nazis made that look bad.  Leading U.S. universities then moved on in the 1930's to develop other methods to ensure that they could pick whichever students they wanted.  For example, geographic diversity (you should take students from Kansas to avoid having too many New Yorkers), preferences for children of alumni, athletic recruitment (you really need a strong lacrosse team and fencing team), well roundedness (students should study hard but not be too nerdy), extracurricular activities, etc.  Jerome Karabel has documented this history in his book [The Chosen](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Chosen.html?id=1Nf3FxMIEB8C).
2. What is Harvard's purpose in educating students?  People often imagine the goal is to educate smart people, and that corruption is the only explanation for why Harvard would deliberately admit a wealthy applicant over someone more talented but poor.  However, this is thinking about it completely wrong.  Harvard's primary goal isn't to educate smart people, but rather to have an impact on the world by educating influential people.  They want to educate the people who are going to grow up to become leaders of all sorts (social, political, commercial, academic, etc.), and while they are happy to help shape who becomes a leader, they know perfectly well that wealth and privilege play a major role.  When Harvard admits someone whose wealth exceeds his intellectual talents, it's because they want to help set the national agenda by providing this person's education.  From this perspective, all the strange admissions criteria are an excuse for Harvard to select whoever they feel has the most potential to change the world, taking into account all aspects of their talents and background.

So what about other universities?  The first axiom of higher education in the U.S. is that everybody imitates the most prestigious universities.  If Harvard, Yale, and Princeton are doing something, then everyone else will follow.  Not necessarily in exactly the same way: different universities may employ very different criteria for admission, thanks to different goals regarding who they want to educate.  But they almost all use the same basic framework for what information is relevant to their decision.

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, it's worth noting arguably the single greatest benefit a university supplies to it's students (even before academics) is the peer group. Part of being a "well-rounded individual" is being able to interact with and learn from people from many backgrounds. Since this is part of the university mission, it must supply students with that varied cohort. Similarly, privilege can be transmitted by proxy. It will be much easier to start a business if you have immediate access to capital in the form of a wealthy roommate.

Comment: Point 2 *needs* to be read by college applicants (and their overbearing families), especially foreign applicants to US schools. Too often schools outside the "top" 5 or 6 are assumed to have poor academics when in reality they simply have fewer future CEOs and senators.

Comment: [The Myth of American Meritocracy by Ron Unz](http://www.theamericanconservative.com/articles/the-myth-of-american-meritocracy/) investigates this line (which made things harder for Jews, now is making it harder for Asians... to get more space for  the children of alumni and other "true Americans"). As of now, Caltech seems to be a meritocratic outlier.

Comment: Although you make some good points, this jaded outlook isn't always warranted. For example, one reason to admit more students from Kansas and not students, even more prepared students, from the coastal metropolises is to increase cohort diversity. Racial and ethnic diversity has been found to improve learning outcomes; I don't know if effects of geographic diversity has been studied, but it certainly makes sense that a New Yorker can gain a broader view of the world by interacting with someone from Kansas.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely not the full story, and there are other arguments in favor of the U.S. system.  As you point out, U.S. universities typically care about diversity (both for reasons of social justice and to create a rich, well-balanced environment), and having flexibility in admissions decisions certainly helps with that.  I emphasized these points mainly because they played a bigger role historically than diversity arguments did, and they aren't as widely understood today.  (But I certainly don't intend to say they are the only factors.)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Well, Caltech certainly started implementing racial quotas as I was leaving. It always had an MIT/Harvard inferiority complex anyway, so it ultimately follows what they do.

Comment: I really like that you mentioned that it was to keep Jews out. This is really the reason there is holistic undergraduate admissions. Perhaps it would have turned out this way anyway, but lets remember the original reason for the change.

Comment: @Philip: "Racial and ethnic diversity has been found to improve learning outcomes" would you happen to have any links on this? Thanks!

Comment: Not handy but I know it was essentially the winning argument by Michigan in *Grutter v. Bollinger* so you can start there. They made a very calculated decision not to argue on the basis of racial equality being a desirable thing, but rather on the learning outcomes. Let me know if you can't find anything and I'll hunt it down.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but it is somewhat of a simplification. I think even Harvard, Stanford, Princeton, Yale, etc. don't know exactly what they want. So I think they muddle their criteria to get a bit of everything -- future politicians, scientists, businesspeople, celebrities, civil rights activists, etc. You can call this group "future leaders", but I think it's a product of uncertainty more than clarity.

Answer (score 32):

My dad was admitted to the university in Novisibiersk in the late sixties, which was indesputably one of the top three technical universities in Russia. He said the only admission criterion was an exam with olympiad-level math questions, which kids studied for all through high school much like some American kids study for the USAMO etc.

Now, the reason I mention this is because he said the reason why admissions here are different not only from Russia but from most of the rest of the world is because in other countries, the students study to serve the state, while in America, the universities provide education as a service to students.

In most other countries, a student is accepted on the basis of the expected value he can bring to society if he is given the appropriate educational opportunity, and then his education is subsidized on the expectation that by studying he can improve the general economy of the state.

However, in America the state pays little (especially for private schools) because education is not a service the individual is doing so he can better the state: it's a service being given to the individual so he can better himself. Even when the government expands measures to pay for student loans etc. the main motivation is to aid poor people in improving themselves, not aiding smart people in improving the state. There isn't anything inherently wrong with this, it's just different and perhaps less efficient.

So that's why American schools don't care so much about academics: they don't care as much about how you do because they aren't investing in you. In fact, you're investing in them, and the return on that investment is an education you can use to get a better job. So they take into account criteria related to how much you'll improve their image, how much you'll be likely to donate later in life, etc.

Answer (score 20):

I'll answer the less-obvious point that other answers so far missed:

> - *Colleges practice sport recruiting, whereby athletes are recruited by the colleges for their athletic promise, over other applicants who might be more qualified in terms of academics.*

The reason for this is that most US colleges are funded in large part by college Alumni donating money.

And college Alumni donate more money if the college has a successful sports team(s).

Here's one study showing causation

https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2012/07/03/report-finds-alumni-giving-among-other-areas-correlated-football-success

> Anderson’s report found that for NCAA Division I Football Bowl Subdivision teams -- teams that compete during the season and are potentially eligible for postseason bowl games -- winning football games increases alumni athletic donations, enhances academic reputation, increases the number of applicants and in-state students, reduces acceptance rates and raises average incoming SAT scores.

Please note that the other benefits are also somewhat explainable - college athletics is pretty visible in US culture, and therefore a university's brand among possible applicants is raised significantly - a LOT more people can name top NCAA winners than top colleges with best biology superstar professor.

A totally unrelated reason is tradition - USA has a very long tradition that sound body is a big plus for a sound mind (it's not a uniquely USA thing, of course - the same idea was held from Ancient Greece to Russia to modern scientific studies results). As such, a good student was always expected to be able to do athletics for well-roundedness.

---

Interestingly, the "legacy" point also is influenced the same monetary way - a wealthy Alumni is more likely to donate to the college if their family member, especially offspring, will attend.

Answer (score 9):

Many of your questions are difficult to answer without a larger industry/history lesson, but you can find much of that information by searching for it.

As for your actual question, why do schools care about non-academic things;

There are many reasons, but these 'non-academic' things are what makes well rounded people that are likely to succeed.  Leaving the country and helping people in need is just one of many ways to show that your mind is broader, which helps creative thinking, which helps problem solving, which helps you to succeed.

The act of doing something non-academic in a group setting shows ability to work cooperatively.  It shows a diverse background, which is regarded as important by many prominent institutions because diversity in academic settings helps improve educational experiences.

In essence, your question is the same as "Why do undergraduate students in Engineering need to take non-engineering classes?"  If you don't know the answer, im sure you can find other posts about this.

Comment: What @user1938107 states is, at least, the official narrative Americans tell themselves when discussing these matters. In reality, it's just what Americans have historically done, and consider important. Whether it *really* makes for better leaders, engineers, or teachers is a separate matter that can be debated. Most European countries don't take such factors in account yet, arguably, have better teachers and engineers. I think the real answer is just: for historical reasons.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth My answer was based on the OP question.  If they said, 'Why do american universities care about these things when the better schools like the ones in europe dont?' I wouldnt have bothered.  My answer is based on what the universities reason is, trying to improve success (as Anon Math) points out, success is impact for many.

Comment: This is from 'Americans' so maybe it cant be trusted, but its a bit more information on why things beyond grades matter to schools: http://www.aaup.org/NR/rdonlyres/97003B7B-055F-4318-B14A-5336321FB742/0/DIVREP.PDF

Comment: I would like this question to be discussed more seriously than the other cynical answers, i.e. these non-academic criteria are a way to exclude minorities. Historically that could be true. Is it still true today? Don't the non-academic considerations actually incentivize American students to do community service and other things outside the classroom? As someone who grew up in Asian high school but went to US colleges, I know that my peers and their parents think very highly of the non-academic considerations.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Don't generalize what 'Americans' do. Your generalizations would be more appropriate for liberal arts schools, not Americans in general. Most American engineers, for example, do indeed focus almost solely on engineering. In my case, for example, I took exactly 3 classes in college that weren't directly related to the work I do as an engineer. One of those was a bowling class that I took just for fun in addition to all of the other classes that I would have taken anyway that semester. Also, I would definitely argue that point about Europe 'having better engineers.' :P

Comment: @reirab: Yours is a fair point. At the same time, the general education requirements at my own state school, Texas A&M, equate to approximately 1/3 of the credit hours students have to take for their 4-year degree. This is true whether you're a liberal arts major or an engineering major. So I think it's not state schools vs liberal arts colleges, but something that may be specific from university to university. Either way, your point is well taken.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth It's starting to be known that character like conscientiousness is a better predictability of success than IQ alone. It is [well written here](http://www.amazon.com/How-Children-Succeed-Curiosity-Character/dp/0544104404/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1429903337&sr=8-1&keywords=how+children+succeed).

Comment: Maybe. But does this correlate well with admission criteria?

Answer (score 6):

### Extra-Curriculars

There are a few reasons why US Colleges make some of these selection criteria. Having extra curricular activities shows a number of potentially important things:

- the ability to juggle more than just school (I can volunteer and play a sport on top of keeping my grades
- travel can indicate a wider range of interesting experiences
- Interesting students will do interesting things, which can be good for recruitment
- Being successful in a variety of areas indicates a general ability to succeed better than being successful in only one (and Universities here gain prestige by having successful alumni).

Something worth noting - in most places in the world University is about specializing. You take one subject, gain mastery in it, move on to work in that subject.  In the US this is not the case.  We value a "broad" education where you are required to study many subjects that have little to do with your major - in fact many people do not decide their majors until a year or two in (we feel this creates "well-rounded" people).  As a result students who have evidence of non-academic achievements can be favored over those who focused their efforts (especially if both candidates have comparable grades).

### Affirmative Action

You highlight on "quotas" (often referred to here as "Affirmative Action"). Ultimately it is a political issue. The idea is to ensure fairness. At one point (basically any time before 1970) a perfectly qualified black woman would be passed over in preference for a white male.  Rules (and often laws) were enacted to say that women (and other minorities) needed to be fairly represented in the school (and business) - the quota was the way to ensure the school would look at the non-preferred candidates.  Legally Affirmative Action is not discrimination, and in many jurisdictions it is still legally mandated.

Whether the practice is discrimination or not is highly subjective (to my incredibly intelligent mother who likely got a chance at earning her BS and MS in Computer Science **only** because Duke had to let women in for their "quota" it was not discrimination).

### Finances

(Disclaimer, there is a large amount of politics in the discussion over what is "necessary spending" for universities in the US, and the high cost of tuition)

The rest of your questions are actually talking about the same point. I am not familiar with universities in India, but in many places in the world universities are fundamentally part of the state - the state either directly runs the institution, or it subsidizes most to all of the cost for the students attending.

In the US there are a few state sponsored schools, but individual US States get to determine the amount of support those schools get, and most schools are not well funded in the state's budget. In addition there are a large number of private schools that do not receive any funding (Harvard, Princeton, Stanford, MIT, etc.). For most schools in the US, they have to fund their own budgets.  These budgets include facility/maintenance fees (paint, lights, utilities, etc.), staff pay (student, faculty, and non-faculty employees), expansion to the campus, and all the other things the school pays for (e.g. having a gym, hosting symposiums, etc.).

Tuition is very high ($20000+ per *year* is pretty common), but even still is often not enough to cover the budget.  Thus the school relies on other things to pull in revenue - research grants can help, but are earmarked for specific projects and do not help with general budget goals. The two other major sources of income Universities can get are donations, and "event fees".

Donations often come from alumni who are grateful for their success.  The school does not want to upset great donors - nor potential future donors - and will give preferential treatment to children of alumni as a result.

"Event Fees" can come from a number of things (e.g. hosting a conference/symposium, putting on a play or concert, etc.), but in general Universities believe that Sporting activities bring in the most money (for the rest of this I will assume that is true, even though there is evidence that is not always the case). Sporting events bring in money through a few avenues:

- More donations from fervent supporters of the school's teams
- Ticket sales
- Merchandise sales
- Advertising
- Concessions
- Some competitions pay winning teams in some way

Because the schools with the best teams get the strongest support and thus the most income from all of those avenues, schools do what they can to ensure their teams are the best. Sometimes the best athletes are exceptional academically, but more often they are not.  Since the school wants the best athletes they will provide scholarships and admission to candidates who might have been disqualified academically.

Comment: I wouldn't generalize the U.S. at all in the manner you've done in your first section. Quite a lot, perhaps a majority, of U.S. college students do indeed choose their major before admission and do focus on it. It's more the liberal arts schools that don't do that, not all schools. Engineering schools will generally focus almost solely on engineering, for example.

Comment: Would just like to point out that affirmative action and quotas are not necessarily the same idea. For instance, if we assign a hypothetical score between 0 and 100 to each applicant, we could add 5 to all applicants from [group X], then proceed as normal. There's no "minimum number" of people we need to admit from group X, but they still got a bit of a boost.

Comment: Universities routine skim a cut (called "overhead") from research grants, and some of that goes into the general budget. The funding agencies keep an eye on overhead levels so there is a limit to how much general funding can be developed in this way, but some definitely is.

Answer (score 6):

Because it is a way for universities to discriminate students while keeping plausible deniability.

Universities in the US have a history of discrimination. After WW1, universities were faced with an influx of immigrant students, in particular Jewish students. To "cope" with this, they started by creating quotas of students (again, in particular, Jewish students). This soon became unacceptable for obvious reasons. This is when universities started to introduce more unusual criteria when evaluating incoming students, such as "geographic diversity", "character", and "familial ascendancy". This in particular included so-called "legacy" criteria, where students were given a bonus if their parents went to the same university.

A key point in all this is that the universities never reveal how much weight they give to each criterion. This makes for a completely opaque selection system. A student can never be sure *why* they were rejected. They can rationalize it by thinking that their "extracurricular" activities were not good enough. But how would they know? It may be another, less tasteful criterion that prevented them from getting in, such as who knows who, where there parents studied, the personal biases of the selection committee regarding ethnicity and religion, and so on.

In practice, this is simply a way for the elite to remain the elite. For example, at Harvard, 29% of students had a parent who went to Harvard. (Think about it; this number is insane.) More than half the students come from the 10% richest families. Students from the 1% richest families are as many as students from the 60% poorest. Students from minorities account for 12.5% of candidates, and 6.7% of accepted students. A study found that in the top 10 US universities, being a "son of" (a former student) gave you the same increase in chances as a 160 points boost on your SAT. In 2011, another study found that in the top 30 universities, children of former students had 45 points more in chances of being accepted (i.e. if based on qualifications the student had 40% chances of being accepted, then their "legacy" means that they actually have 85% of being accepted).

---

Note that unfortunately this is not limited to the USA. This year's changes in undergrad admissions in France are starting to implement similar ideas, although on a smaller scale, and some universities try to be open about the weight assigned to each criterion. I would not be surprised if this happened in other countries too.

---

A lot of the information in this answer comes from [this article](https://www.monde-diplomatique.fr/2018/06/KAHLENBERG/58772) written by [Richard Kahlenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Kahlenberg). The article is not freely accessible and is written in French, but below is the (freely accessible) list of references used in the article, most in English.

> (1) Michael Lind, « Legacy preferences in a democratic republic »,
>   dans Richard D. Kahlenberg (sous la dir. de), Affirmative Action for
>   the Rich, op. cit.
>
> (2) Jessica M. Wang et Brian P. Yu, « Meet the class of 2021 », The
>   Harvard Crimson, 2017.
>
> (3) Richard V. Reeves, Dream Hoarders : How the American Upper Middle
>   Class Is Leaving Everyone Else in the Dust, Why That Is a Problem, and
>   What to Do About It, Brookings Institution Press, Washington, DC,
>   2017. Lire également « Classe sans risque », Le Monde diplomatique, octobre 2017.
>
> (4) Cf. Daniel Golden, The Price of Admission : How America’s Ruling
>   Class Buys Its Way Into Elite Colleges — and Who Gets Left Outside the
>   Gates, Three Rivers Press, New York, 2007.
>
> (5) John Brittain et Eric L. Bloom, « Admitting the truth : the effect
>   of affirmative action, legacy preferences and the meritocratic ideal
>   on students of color in college admissions », dans Affirmative Action
>   for the Rich, op. cit.
>
> (6) Thomas J. Espenshade, Chang Y. Chung et Joan L. Walling, «
>   Admission preferences for minority students, athletes, and legacies at
>   elite universities » (PDF), Social Science Quarterly, vol. 85, n° 5,
>   Hoboken (New Jersey), décembre 2004.
>
> (7) Michael Hurwitz, « The impact of legacy status on undergraduate
>   admissions at elite colleges and universities », Economics of
>   Education Review, vol. 30, n° 3, Amsterdam, juin 2011.
>
> (8) Steve D. Shadowen, Sozi Pedro Tulante et Shara L. Alpern, « No
>   distinctions except those which merit originates : the unlawfulness of
>   legacy preferences in public and private universities », Santa Clara
>   Law Review, vol. 49, n° 1, 2009.
>
> (9) Thomas R. Dye, Who’s Running America ? The Obama Reign, Paradigm
>   Publishers, Boulder (Colorado), 2014.

Answer (score 5):

I think a lot of the other answers here have some good points, but I think the most important thing you need to remember about universities in America is that they are BUSINESSES. Education is the primary service that they provide, but they are also selling things like prestige (how good does your University degree look on your resume/CV?), contacts/networking, sports programs (many professional athletes start at colleges that have top-notch sports teams), etc.

My guess is that the United States probably has more universities than any other country and therefore has the most competition amongst them than in other countries. A university's admissions "formula" is like a food company's recipe or a technology company's patents - it provides a competitive advantage (hopefully) and is constantly reviewed and tweaked in an effort to maximize profits.

When looked at through the eyes of a business looking to maximize profit, it's pretty obvious why legacy students, promising student athletes, minorities and foreigners, etc are admitted - it all ultimately leads to more revenue over time.

Some examples:

- Endowments are the #1 source of funding for universities. Harvard's is around $35B (yes, that's BILLION) while Yale's is around $25B. Thus it's obvious why sons and daughters of alumni are given preferential treatment in admissions.
- College sports is BIG business. Recruiting and admitting talented student athletes is a no-brainer for universities.
- Part of the "university business" is hiring and keeping the best professors. Famous people like former Secretary of State Madeleine Albright, Henry Louis Gates Jr., and Cornell West can teach anywhere they want. I bet they don't want to teach at a university with a homogenous (i.e., dull) student body. Professors are also very liberal and therefore support initiatives like affirmative action. Also, they want to go where the money is!!

Like I said, other people have some good points, but having received my undergraduate degree from Harvard and my master's degree from New York University I've seen firsthand how these educational institutions are just like any other business in America.

Answer (score 2):

One further point that I haven't seen yet in the other answers relates to a general philosophy of education.

My impression is that in many countries, the philosophy of education is centered around the development of technical skills.  In the United States, however, it is often held that the primary purpose of education is to develop a creative and insightful mind.

This philosophy is reflected in the "breadth" or "common core" requirements that appear at many universities, which assume that a student cannot be considered "well educated" unless they have been taught to think in ways other than is preferred by by their discipline.  For example, as an undergraduate at MIT, I was required to take classes from a range of scientific disciplines (math, biology, physics, chemistry), and also a humanities course in every semester, as well as doing a humanities focus entirely unrelated to my major.

This notion that intellectual "breadth" is as important as intellectual "depth" seems to play a strong role in the way in which admissions are handled for US undergraduates.  Whether it is truly a good or bad thing is something there is currently no clear answer to, but some have argued that this philosophy may be an important contributor to the highly successful US "startup" and small business culture.

Comment: My impression is that in many European countries, these broader subjects are just covered in the equivalent of high school instead.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft In the US, they are also covered in high school.  University courses, however, tend to go much deeper and expect much higher performance out of students than high school courses in the humanities, just as they do for technical courses.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the specific course and the country. As far as I can tell at least the language courses tend to be very introductory (and those math courses that seem to be commonly taken by non majors certainly cover less than what I learned in high school).

Answer (score 2):

Specific example of why this is considered:  MIT has been known to turn down people with top grades when there's evidence that they will deal very poorly with no longer being at the top of their class. Someone who can draw good grades and sustain extracurricular activities is more likely to survive in that environment than someone who got those grades by doing nothing but study.

Answer (score 0):

Extra curricular activities indicate levels of involvement and discipline that grades alone don't always reflect.  If two students have equivalent grades and equivalent coursework, it's more impressive if one student was able to do that while participating in a sport, a music group, and volunteering while the other student did not have these additional time constraints.  A university would likely see a student with strong extracurricular involvement as one who would be more likely to be involved in activities in college, which can benefit the school by improving its image ("look at our students giving back to the community") or through research (the "do it all" types may be more likely to participate in undergrad research).  Colleges like well-rounded students, and having extracurricular involvement shows well-roundedness.

Legacy students...that's an entirely different matter in my opinion.  That may be more to appease the alumni parents who might donate.  Also, if the parents are alums, the kid may be more likely to matriculate (because colleges want a high matriculation rate among accepted students) and be successful (if the parents were able to graduate, the kid probably would as well).

Answer (score 0):

In the US, it all comes down to decentralized control and funding.

> Education is primarily a State and local responsibility in the United
>   States.
>
> [[source]](http://www2.ed.gov/about/overview/fed/role.html)

This is actually a consequence of the US constitution which limits the reach of the Federal government in States affairs. Even in the few instances where some Federal funds are allocated to education, the Federal government will usually disburse those funds and leave the implementation details to the States themselves.

> It is States and communities, as well as public and private
>   organizations of all kinds, that establish schools and colleges,
>   develop curricula, and determine requirements for enrollment and
>   graduation. The structure of education finance in America reflects
>   this predominant State and local role.
>
> [[source]](http://www2.ed.gov/about/overview/fed/role.html)

In other words, there is not one single academic standard that runs across the entire United States and there is not a single standard way to measure the abilities of students. One could say that the SAT and the ACT are such standards, but those are not government-sponsored, nor government-mandated, they're just private and proprietary products owned and licensed by the companies that developed them, and those tests are just partial bandaid solutions that have evolved over time as a direct result of not having standards in the first place.

In any case, even if academic abilities could be measured accurately, there is still the issue of which entities and special interests are funding the University. If it's a particular State, it wants the children of its electorates (this is usually written in their charter). If it's private donors, then it means they want their children and the children of their friends to be accepted (that's also written in their charter, but instead of using the word "nepotism", the euphemism "legacy" is used instead). If it's the military (through the ROTC, or the GI Bill), it wants its recruits and its veterans and/or their dependents to be accepted by the schools it funds (keep this in mind if you ever want to become a Medical Doctor and don't have the best absolute grades for it).

If a University was started by funds from a particular religion, or if it is supported by local politicians, or by local private interests, that are predominantly one religion, then it will tend to favor members from that particular religion. The same goes for Universities that practice racial discrimination (whether be it the negative kind of discrimination and preferential nepotism, or affirmative action which is supposed to correct past discrimination and past nepotism).

And if a University depends on the funds from college sports, either franchising, rebroadcasting rights, increased publicity, and/or increased donations from Alumni, then it will do its very best to recruit athletes for its sports teams through its admission process.

In the US, professional sports leagues are government-backed monopolies (exempt from anti-trust regulations). Those sports leagues artificially limit the number of teams they allow to very low numbers (at least compared to our population size). And semi-professional college leagues end up filling the gaps left by professional leagues, except that schools are legally required not to pay their athletes (except for tuition and expense reimbursements), thus creating a real bargain for each school.

Also on the athletic side of things, even if you're not good enough to play on a college league for a University, having attended school both in France and in the US, I'll disagree with you and say that athleticism probably has a bigger role in France than in the US. The French school system has a standardized and a rigorous way of testing high school students for general physical education, which will figure as a part of their Baccalauréat and therefore indirectly be a part of the overall criteria used for University admissions. But physical education in the US is largely dependent on the particular high school you attended. In California, where I attended, it was basically a joke (and thus can not be relied on for University admissions, unless you took sports as extracurricular activities, thus this would explain why they would want you to list those extracurricular sports on college applications).

Answer (score -2):

I always assumed parents would complain that their precious child was not being measured accurately if admissions criteria did not include ridiculous things like hiking in the Himalayas.

But there’s also not really any choice. As a current college student in a fairly elite college with fairly elite stats, I of all people know that high-school GPAs and the SAT are meaningless for college success. A lot of high schools, like inner city or rural schools, produce kids with high GPAs and the inability to do basic math. The SAT is something you can study maybe three weeks for and get a full score on. The most impressive thing I can see on a resume is doing well in Math Olympiad or high-school programming/robotics contests. That is not something available to everyone.

In the end, colleges need to separate kids somehow, and the basic criteria, like GPA and standardized test scores are just not adequate. So they turn to feel-good things like trips to Nepal. It’s almost not the college’s fault... except they could imitate the Asian system and administer their own personal examinations for entrance. That would make a lot more sense, but you would have to refer to my first comment about over-sensitive parents and college administrators as for why that would not work.

Comment: i would be way more impressed by someone substantially contributing to an open source software project before graduating high school then doing well in a programming/robotics contest. Another example is that   I personally knew a fellow classmate when I was in high school that was actively involved in fighting for the rights of diabetics including health care rights on a fairly high level which was impressive. These are only some examples of extra curricular activities that might hold weight other then the aforementioned hiking in the Himalayas (which is completely irrelevant).

Answer (score -6):

As [Najib Idrissi](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/9646/najib-idrissi) pointed out, nonacademic criteria play a large role in the admissions process in the US, because it is a way for universities to discriminate students while keeping plausible deniability. It is a common misconception, however, that it's mostly rich White men who benefit from this:

> Perhaps the most detailed statistical research into the actual
>   admissions practices of American universities has been conducted by
>   Princeton sociology professor Thomas J. Espenshade and his colleagues,
>   whose results were summarized in his 2009 book No Longer Separate, Not
>   Yet Equal, co-authored with Alexandria Walton Radford. Their findings
>   provide an empirical look at the individual factors that dramatically
>   raise or lower the likelihood of acceptance into the leading American
>   universities which select the next generation of our national elites.
>
> The research certainly supports the widespread perception that
>   non-academic factors play a major role in the process, including
>   athletic ability and “legacy” status. But as we saw earlier, even more
>   significant are racial factors, with black ancestry being worth the
>   equivalent of 310 points, Hispanics gaining 130 points, and Asian
>   students being penalized by 140 points, all relative to white
>   applicants on the 1600 point Math and Reading SAT scale.
>
> [source](https://www.theamericanconservative.com/articles/the-myth-of-american-meritocracy/)

Here's how it typically works:

> Consider the case of Tiffany Wang, a Chinese immigrant student raised
>   in the Silicon Valley area, where her father worked as an engineer.
>   Although English was not her first language, her SAT scores were over
>   100 points above the Wesleyan average, and she ranked as a National
>   Merit Scholarship semifinalist, putting her in the top 0.5 percent of
>   high school students (not the top 2 percent as Steinberg mistakenly
>   claims). Nevertheless, the admissions officer rated her just so-so in
>   academics, and seemed far more positively impressed by her ethnic
>   activism in the local school’s Asian-American club. Ultimately, he
>   stamped her with a “Reject,” but later admitted to Steinberg that she
>   might have been admitted if he had been aware of the enormous time and
>   effort she had spent campaigning against the death penalty, a
>   political cause near and dear to his own heart. Somehow I suspect that
>   a student who boasted of leadership in pro-death penalty activism
>   among his extracurriculars might have fared rather worse in this
>   process. And presumably for similar reasons, Tiffany was also rejected
>   by all her other prestigious college choices, including Yale, Penn,
>   Duke, and Wellesley, an outcome which greatly surprised and
>   disappointed her immigrant father.
>
> There was also the case of half-Brazilian Julianna Bentes, with slight
>   black ancestry, who came from a middle-class family and attended on a
>   partial scholarship one of America’s most elite prep schools, whose
>   annual tuition now tops $30,000; her SAT scores were somewhat higher
>   than Tiffany’s, and she was an excellent dancer. The combination of
>   her academic ability, dancing talent, and “multiracial” background
>   ranked her as one of America’s top college recruitment prospects,
>   gaining her admission and generous financial packages from Harvard,
>   Yale, Stanford and every other elite university to which she applied,
>   including the University of Chicago’s most prestigious academic
>   scholarship award and a personal opportunity to meet Chelsea Clinton
>   while visiting Stanford, which she did, before ultimately selecting
>   Yale.
>
> Finally, there was the case of Becca Jannol, a girl from a very
>   affluent Jewish family near Beverly Hills, who attended the same elite
>   prep school as Julianna, but with her parents paying the full annual
>   tuition. Despite her every possible advantage, including test-prep
>   courses and retaking the exam, her SAT scores were some 240 points
>   lower on the 1600 point scale, placing her toward the bottom of the
>   Wesleyan range, while her application essay focused on the
>   philosophical challenges she encountered when she was suspended for
>   illegal drug use. But she was a great favorite of her prep school
>   counselor, who was an old college friend of the Wesleyan admissions
>   officer, and using his discretion, he stamped her “Admit.” Her dismal
>   academic record then caused this initial decision to be overturned by
>   a unanimous vote of the other members of the full admissions
>   committee, but he refused to give up, and moved heaven and earth to
>   gain her a spot, even offering to rescind the admissions of one or
>   more already selected applicants to create a place for her. Eventually
>   he got her shifted from the Reject category to wait-list status, after
>   which he secretly moved her folder to the very top of the large
>   waiting list pile.
>
> In the end “connections” triumphed, and she received admission to
>   Wesleyan, although she turned it down in favor of an offer from more
>   prestigious Cornell, which she had obtained through similar means. But
>   at Cornell, she found herself “miserable,” hating the classes and
>   saying she “didn’t see the usefulness of [her] being there.” However,
>   her poor academic ability proved no hindrance, since the same
>   administrator who had arranged her admission also wrangled her a quick
>   entrance into a special “honors program” he personally ran, containing
>   just 40 of the 3500 students in her year. This exempted her from all
>   academic graduation requirements, apparently including classes or
>   tests, thereby allowing her to spend her four college years mostly
>   traveling around the world while working on a so-called “special
>   project.” After graduation, she eventually took a job at her father’s
>   successful law firm, thereby realizing her obvious potential as a
>   member of America’s ruling Ivy League elite, or in her own words, as
>   being one of “the best of the best.”
>
> [source](https://www.theamericanconservative.com/articles/the-myth-of-american-meritocracy/)

Comment: Whether or not one agrees with the stance/opinion of this answer, it should be edited down and not just a copy-paste of a large chunk of text. It also doesn't seem to address the question "why does X happen", it merely quotes at length some sources saying "X has led to Consequence Y which we think is very bad"

Comment: @YemonChoi : I DID respond to the question "Why do undergraduate admissions in the U.S take into account nonacademic criteria?", explaining that it is a way for universities to discriminate students while keeping plausible deniability. And I quoted from a source that addresses this issue in great detail to refute one of the most common misconceptions about who is discriminated and why!